# how to scale a specific Date value in d3 js

Tags: d3.js

Time Intervals in d3 have second, minute, day...scales is there a possibilty to intoduce time like this year.month.day.hour.min.second that means introduce the value time in a specific way?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you're referring to the [`.ticks()` function](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Scales#wiki-ticks) for time scales. Yes, you can specify arbitrary values there, e.g. by simply passing in the number of ticks you want without explicitly specifying an interval. You can of course also specify any interval you like, e.g.

```
scale.ticks(d3.time.minute, 23);
```

for ticks every 23 minutes.

Comment: Thx for the ansewer but I think this is what I need:parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").parse;

Comment: Ok, so you want to parse dates? Sorry but that isn't clear from the question at all.

Comment: I tried with d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").parse; but is still not working ! could you plz take a look to this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19399745/time-parsing-and-scaling-for-d3js-graphs