# Time parsing and scaling for d3js graphs

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/amani1988/cfk8Y/2/) that draws a d3js multichart object, the value time:Years values are given in this format Year=2011...
with this time format the code works fine but once I wanted to change the data time in this format Year=(Y-M-D H:M:S)

```
var data = [{"Year":"2011-10-01 20:46:04","Happy":"63.4","Sad":"42.7","Angry":"12.2","Surprised":"44.2"},
{"Year":"2012-10-01 17:02:04","Happy":"75.4","Sad":"32.7","Angry":"78.2","Surprised":"82.2"},
{"Year":"2013-10-01 19:55:44","Happy":"73.4","Sad":"20.7","Angry":"92.2","Surprised":"75.4"}];
```

I parsed the data Year:

```
 var parseDate=d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").parse; //line 13
 d.Year=parseDate(d.Year);  //and then line 53
```

But it is not working, how can I read data Year in this format:(Y-M-D H:M:S)

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Do you get an error message?

Comment: no errors but the graph dont show up once I change and parse the new data array

Comment: Could you please provide the code with your changes so we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: Yes It is already provided above in the link and the changes are commented lines ( mentionned lines in the question) http://jsfiddle.net/amani1988/cfk8Y/2/

Comment: My mistake I put the non updated link: I edit the link in the question now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your example is that you're converting all properties of the objects to numbers. This works if the date is just the year, but not if it is a string that needs to be parsed. In your case, you don't need to do this conversion anyway because you can give the numbers as numbers rather than strings directly. That is, you don't need

```
for(var prop in d) {
    if(d.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        d[prop] = parseFloat(d[prop]);
    }
}
```

Working jsfiddle with the conversion code removed [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cfk8Y/3/).